# locking on dictionary of structs not working between 2 threads?

Tags: c#, .net, locking

C#, .Net2.0, XP, Zen

I have 2 threads accessing a shared dictionary of structures, each thread via an event.
At the beginning of the event I lock the dictionary, remove some structures, and exit the lock+event.
Yet somehow the 2nd thread|event is finding some of the removed structures.

Conceptually I must be doing something wrong for this to be happening? I thought locking was supposed to make it thread safe?

Comment: Language/platform/framework/state of mind?

Comment: Please provide a short example program that demonstrates this behaviour.

Comment: Show us some code - ideally, the minimal code that still has the problem. With luck, getting FROM where you are now TO that minimal code will show you what's going wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I can suggest without seeing the code:

1. Verify that the *same* lock object is used in both methods, e.g. if your lock statement is locking on a variable that is thread local, it won't work.

---

```
object _guard = new object();

void threadMethod1()
{
    lock(_guard) {...} //data is modified inside
}

void threadMethod2()
{
    lock(_guard) {...} //data is modified inside
}
```

not like this:

```
void threadMethod1()
{
    lock(new object()) {...} //data is modified inside
}

void threadMethod2()
{
    lock(new object()) {...} //data is modified inside
}
```

---

2 Depending on the .NET version you are using, there might be no need for locking if you use BlockingCollection or something from Parallel namespace.

Comment: @Rancur3p1c: cool! Thanks for accepting my answer as one. Any details why it was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to post a comment - otherwise I would.

Locking does work, but here are common pitfalls -

What are you locking? Is it always the same instance of the dictionary? 
Locking on value types does not work - you just lock the box - then the other thread locks a different box. So this code is bad:

```
int x;
void SomeThreadedfunc()
{
   lock((object)x) // does not work because x is boxed
   { 
      x++; 
   }
}
```

However this works:

```
object lockX = new object();
int x;
void SomeThreadedfunc()
{
   lock(lockX) // works 
   { 
      x++; 
   }
}
```

Comment: -1 The first example is not valid. `x` will not be boxed - you cannot lock on value types full stop.

Comment: @chibacity - my bad, you are correct you would have to explicitly box it  lock((object)x) // does not work because x is boxed
   { 
      x++; 
   }

Comment: Hmm... I tend to disagree. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664735(VS.71).aspx states that "The expression of a lock statement must denote a value of a reference-type." x has to be boxed for compiler to succeed.

Comment: @Schultz9999 - you are correct - x gets boxed when you explicitly cast it to object. The problem is each time that boxing happens there is a different instance of the box created and so the locking does nothing. Also I corrected my code after chibacity post. Up to that point it was not valid.

Comment: @Neil: no argument here - I tried to say it's boxed. I supposed I haven't seen your original post. I was disagreeing with chibacity actually.

Comment: @Schultz9999 - my original code had the lock(x){...} which would not have compiled. That is what chibacity objected to. I corrected it. so at the time of his comment he was correct.